# SharePoint workflow keep failing randomly

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

Some workflows are failing and I got this Error randomly "The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information."

I checked all the sites columns and types of information and I could not find any issue. Without any changes, I restart the workflow for the item and it fixes itself.

I am trying to figure it what the cause root of this issue instead of restarting them manually when it fails. I also added the system pause to workflows as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since it’s a random issue, you can try to clear the SharePoint Designer cache and reconnect the SharePoint site.

Then republish the workflow and check again.